# mysql select rows that dont exist in table and dont have value

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have 2 tables

**table1:**

```
+-------------------------+--------+
| Playername              | Gender |
+-------------------------+--------+
| Kendall dddddd          | Female |
| Ivy xxxxxxxx            | Female |
| Carson xxxxxxx          | Female |
+-------------------------+--------+
```

**table2:**

```
+----------------+----------+
| Playername     | EvalYear |
+----------------+----------+
| Kendall dddddd |     2014 |
| Carson xxxxxxx |     2013 |
+----------------+----------+
```

**Query**

```
SELECT table1.Playername, table1.Gender, table2.EvalYear
FROM table1 
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.Playername = table2.PlayerName
where table2.EvalYear is Null and table2.EvalYear != '2014'
```

I need the query to return **Ivy** and **Carson** names.

Comment: table.Playername doesn't exist per the table structure you showed. I'm assuming table2 = PlayerEvals because it's used in your query but doesn't exist in the table structure. Please clean up your question if you would like help with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing a `LEFT JOIN`, you should put conditions that must be matched in the second table in the `ON` clause, not the `WHERE` clause. Since you're returning rows that don't match the year, you need to change the sense of the test.

```
SELECT table1.Playername, table1.Gender, table2.EvalYear
FROM table1 
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.Playername = table2.PlayerName AND table2.EvalYear = 2014
```

Result:

```
+----------------+--------+----------+
| Playername     | Gender | EvalYear |
+----------------+--------+----------+
| Kendall dddddd | Female |     2014 |
| Ivy xxxxxxxx   | Female |     NULL |
| Carson xxxxxxx | Female |     NULL |
+----------------+--------+----------+
```

Comment: This gives me all of the players (rows) that dont exist in table 1.  How would I get this list AND also the Names that match the EvalYear = 2014?  So from the above table I need a list:  Kendall  2014| Ivy  NULL | Carson  NULL

Comment: The question says you want to return `Ivy` and `Carson`. That's what my query returns.

Comment: I removed the `WHERE` clause. Now it returns all the rows from table1. If the year in table2 is 2014, that shows up in the result, otherwise it's `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

**Query**

```
SELECT table1.Playername, table1.Gender, table2.EvalYear
FROM table1 
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.Playername = table2.PlayerName
where PlayerEvals.EvalYear is Null or PlayerEvals !='2014'
```